# How can I grind sesame seeds in my coffee grinder better?

Tags: seeds, grinding

When I grind sesame alone or with flax seeds, I can see that many of the sesame seeds are not ground.

When I grind several things together including sesame, flax seeds and mixed nuts, like walnuts, almonds, and cashews, the powder becomes more stuck together, and I can't see unground sesames.

Does the second way indeed grind sesame seeds finer or are the unground sesame seeds hidden in the powder?

My coffee grinder is [KRUPS F203 Electric Spice and Coffee Grinder with Stainless Steel Blades, 3-Ounce, Black](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00004SPEU):

[image] [image]

Comment: Ground hulled sesame seeds form a paste - tahini.  There is probably too much oil in the sesame seeds to get a dry powder.

Answer (score 2):

Grind the sesame seeds separately using a pestle and mortar (if the seeds really have to be ground).

Grinding sesame seeds manually isn't as hard as grinding the other nuts/seeds that you're mentioning - I think it's just the size that helps them not be hit by the grinder blades so effectively.

So, pestle them down and add to the mix afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your mix is becoming sticky when you mix nuts with your sesame is that you are making the nuts into a butter before your grinder can reach the small seeds. You should try grinding the sesame by itself, however try and pack the grinder as much as allowed. That way you'll allow the blade to always be working on something. Also make sure to scrape the sides and mix a couple of times in the process. 
Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I did that recently by first slowly roasting the sesame seeds in a frying pan over low heat. When the roasting is done, you let the seeds cool down. Then you grind. It works well.